# How does bucket get implemented in hash table

Tags: java, collections, hashtable

I am new to Hash Tables and if I am not wrong, I understood that the we generate hash(value) and decide which bucket should the value be kept, but how are keys generated that are present in the buckets ?

Comment: Keys are generated by hashCode java function available in every Object.

Comment: You don't generate `hash(value);` you generate `hash(key);`. You use the key for insert and lookup, not the value.